# Make string format ignore 'None'

Tags: python

Is there a way in python such that when you do

```
foo = "foo"
bar = None
"{} {}".format(foo, bar)
```

it doesn't print None as the value of bar?

ie. It should result in `"foo "` and not `"foo None"`

Comment: You'll need to test the value of each variable, then call `.format()`.

Comment: What Python "should" do is print the string representation of each value.  Since `str{None)` is `"None"`... Python is doing what it "should"!

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that looks like this `"number {default:4}".format(number)`

Answer (score 13):

If you are assigning `None` to your variable, you will have to set some kind of condition around controlling what output you want. Here is a simple example:

```
"{} {}".format(foo, "" if bar is None else bar)
```

Another way of looking at the above that behaves the same way, is writing it this way as well:

```
"{} {}".format(foo, bar if bar is not None else "")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def none_to_empty(s):
    return "" if s is None else s

def format_without_nones(format_string, *args):
    return format_string.format(*map(none_to_empty, args))

format_without_nones("{} {}", foo, bar)
```

Look up varargs and the map function if you don't understand how `format_without_nones` works. It's just equivalent to saying

```
"{} {}".format(none_to_empty(foo), none_to_empty(bar))
```

which doesn't look as pretty since you might have to repeat `none_to_empty` a lot of time. But `none_to_empty` can also be used directly if you only want to apply it to some arguments but let `None` appear for others, e.g.:

```
"{} {}".format(foo, none_to_empty(bar))
```

which is still nicer than having `"" if bar is None else bar` for every single `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.6 you can evaluate expressions inside `f'string`s
So a ternary operator like the one used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33271237/22049099) answer should do the trick

```
foo = "foo"
bar = None
string = f"{foo if foo is not None else ''} {bar if bar is not None else ''}"
```

Answer (score -6):

I don't think there's a way to do it automatically, you could do this:

```
"{} {}".format(foo, bar or "")
```

Comment: Fails if `bar is False`

Comment: I don't think you can monkey patch the `__str__` of python's builtin string class...

Comment: @mgilson Indeed you can't.  My mistake.